# Filter objects by exact position of character

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a list of codes where each character as a meaning:

i.e.

> code:
>
> 1) 0000.ABCD
>
> 2) 1111.CACC
>
> position: 012345678

I want' to make a search for all the codes with `A` at position 5.

> 1) 0000.ABCD

So the research should return only the first code.

I've looked at django look_up functions but this isn't the case neither for an iexact or an icontains.

Is there a way to make a search like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regex lookup.

```
Model.objects.filter(code__regex=r'^.{5}A')
```

Comment: Beat me to it, heres the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#regex) link